# how to import SQL database file into wamp server

Tags: database, server, wamp

I am beginner in programming..
I have already MySQL 5.1 Installed in my pc .Now I am installed wamp server  which has MySQL 5.6 and want to Access all the database of 5.1 in MySQL5.6....

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Export each of your databases using MYSQL5.1 to files in a safe place

Stop the old MYSQL Server using service.msc -> stop service

Start WAMPServer, make the icon is green

Import all the databases to the new database manager.

Now go back and change the Startup type of the OLD MYSQL to Manual or bettern still Disable the old MYSQL Server using service.msc

Remember unless you know what you are doing running 2 MySQL servers is a bad idea and will just get you completely confused.